# How to shutdown computer with ubuntu from a program?

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, c++

How can I add a 'shutdown option' to my program?

Or how can I send commands to terminal from my program (so I can send a `sudo shutdown` command) ?

Planning to write in c++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18766704/2072269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `system()` function defined in the header `stdlib.h`.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  system("dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 \"org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff\" boolean:true");
  retrun 0;
}
```

This is advised over `sudo shutdown` because the former does not require root privileges. Or your program will ask for the administrative password before shutdown.

You can get more information about the system command from it's manpage:

```
man system
```

Answer (score 1):

> … how can I send commands to terminal from my program …

Using `system`, eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("/bin/ls -la");
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("sudo shutdown");
}
```

---

*Example*

```
% gcc foo.cpp
% ./a.out
[sudo] password for aboettger:

% cat foo.cpp 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("sudo shutdown");
}
```

Comment: `sudo` probably will crap out when called from `system`.

Comment: @muru Seems to work, I have added an example.